# How to print out a pointer using printf under xv6?

Tags: xv6

I am using xv6 and I want to print out the pointer's address returned from `sbrk`

I am trying to use:
`printf(sbrk(0),"%p\n");`

But when I tried to make, it complained:

```
error: passing argument 1 of ‘printf’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
    printf(sbrk(0), "%p\n");
```

Is there a way to print out a pointer under xv6?

If you want I can share you with the make file - but I just cloned it from the xv6 repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `printf(1, "%p\n", sbrk(0));`?

The xv6 `printf` function (from [printf.c](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/eeb7b415dbcb12cc362d0783e41c3d1f44066b17/printf.c)) need one extra parameter given first: the `fd` number in which you want to write.